# youtube api .getPlaylistIndex() no longer seems to work?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a web app that was built up using the youtube api v3 and for some reason now **.getPlaylistIndex()** is always returning **-1** this just recently happened and caused a major break in the functionality of the site.

There was no changes in the code base to production over the last week and was working last week, but yesterday (or possibly Monday) it broke. There had to be some change within the API that caused these issues. But I was unable to see anything related to this issue posted anywhere...

If anyone has seen this issue and have some kind of link or reference to what was changed, if it is going to be fixed or if that function was deprecated? The only thing I can do at this point is rework all of my code to get around using this function anymore.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up an error in implementation that was in our code, but also because of a change in how things worked through the youtube api. The original coder had set up the youtube player to load the playlist, but then they loaded the start video again

```
channelPlayer.loadPlaylist(currentPlayListArray, selectedVidIdx);
//channelPlayer.loadVideoById(selectedVid);   <<<< This was breaking functionality
channelPlayer.playVideo();
channelPlayer.setLoop(true);
channelPlayer.unMute();
```

This had been working (with the commented out line). Up until last weekend the playlist was not overwritten in the player by the loading of a single video. It seems the functionality has changed where it no longer loads the video ontop of a playlist that was previously loaded. Now it overwrites the playlist of the player instead of concatenating?

Again this was an internal error, but the random change in functionality in the api caused this to actually cause the issue we ran into.